# How to override functions from the Web API when writing a Firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

For research purposes, I am trying to write a web-extension that override some part of the web APIs (for example `setItem`, `getItem`, or `removeItem` from the [`Storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) interface).

Unfortunately, when trying the following:

index.js

```js
Storage.prototype.setItem = function(a, b) { return 42; }
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "cool-extension-name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "A useful description.",
  "icons": {"48": "icons/potatoes.jpg"},
  "content_scripts": [{
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["index.js"]
  }]
}
```

Then using `web-ext run`, and opening Firefox's WebConsole after loading any webpage.

```
$ window.localStorage.setItem(1, 2)
undefined
```

I would have hoped it to return `42`.
What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the code via `window.eval()` to access the context of the web page itself. For example:

```
browser.tabs.executeScript(1, {
  code: 'window.eval("Storage.prototype.setItem = function(a, b) { return 42; }")'
})
```

See also:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Using_eval_in_content_scripts